# Database Design: replace a boolean column with a timestamp column?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design, relational-database

Earlier I have created tables this way:

```
create table workflow (
    id number primary key,
    name varchar2(100 char) not null,
    is_finished number(1) default 0 not null,
    date_finished date
);
```

Column is_finished indicates whether the workflow finished or not. Column date_finished is when the workflow was finished.

Then I had the idea "I don't need is_finished as I can just say: where data_finished is not null", and I designed without is_finished column:

```
create table workflow (
    id number primary key,
    name varchar2(100 char) not null,
    date_finished date
);
```

(We use Oracle 10)

Is it a good or bad idea? I've heard you can not have an index on a column with NULL values, so `where data_finished is not null` will be very slow on big tables.

Comment: How many rows will there be in the table typically?  And how many of those will not be finished?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a *right* way to index null values, and it doesn't use a FBI. Oracle *will* index null values, but it will NOT index null LEAF values in the tree. So, you *could* eliminate the column `is_finished` and create the index like this.

```
CREATE INDEX ON workflow (date_finished, 1);
```

Then, if you check the explain plan on this query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM workflow WHERE date_finished is null;
```

You might see the index being used (if the optimizer is happy).

Back to the original question: looking at the variety of answers here, I think there is no *right* answer. I may have a personal preference to eliminate a column if it is unnecessary, but I also don't like overloading the meaning of columns either. There are two concepts here:

1. The record has finished. `is_finished`
2. The record finished on a particular date. `date_finished`

Maybe you need to keep these separate, maybe you don't. When I think about eliminating the `is_finished` column, it bothers me. Down the road, the situation may arise where the record finished, but you don't know precisely when. Perhaps you have to import data from another source and the date is unknown. Sure, that's not in the business requirements now, but things change. What do you do then? Well, you have to put some dummy value in the `date_finished` column, and now you've compromised the data a bit. Not horribly, but there is a rub there. The little voice in my head is shouting *YOU'RE DOING IT WRONG* when I do things like that.

My advice, keep it separate. You're talking about a tiny column and a very skinny index. Storage should not be an issue here.

> Rule of Representation: Fold knowledge
>   into data so program logic can be
>   stupid and robust.
>
> -Eric S. Raymond

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you mean that an index on (date_finished,1) is or is not function-based. However, for the record Oracle does regard that as a function-based index.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I was inaccurate when I stated that my solution does not use a FBI. What I should say is that I am not manipulating the column which I am attempting to index.

Answer (score 15):

> Is it a good or bad idea?

Good idea.

You've eliminated space taken by a redundant column; the DATE column serves double duty--you know the work was finished, and *when*.

> I've heard like you can't have an index on a column with NULL values, so "where data_finished is not null" will be very slow on big tables.

That's incorrect.  Oracle indexes ignore NULL values.

[You can create a function based index in order to get around the NULL values not being indexed](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_null_idx.htm), but most DBAs I've encountered *really* don't like them so be prepared for a fight.

Comment: Wow, sorry my comment wasn't fast enough for you.

Comment: You save no space, in fact you waste much more space. You also make the data incomprehensible it's a lose-lose answer.

Comment: @Stephanie Page: Can't waste what you're no longer using, so how do you come to the conclusion that getting rid of redundant column wastes space?  The DATE column is called `finished_date`--again, how is that incomprehensible?

Comment: There was too much to put in a comment, I had to add an answer.

Comment: Just a comment about the space saved. Let's say that the number column will take 4 bytes (it should 1 byte only for 0/1). So for a million records that will be ~4MB wichi is < $1. Not a huge save IMHO! As for queries, is_finished = 0 or date_finished is null, I would say it is a personal taste.

Comment: Whose taste? A database isn't for you the developer/architect. It's for everyone. Your data will outlive applications every time. NULL means nothing, nada, zilch. Saying it means the job is done WILL be confusing at some point to someone. Guaranteed. IS_UNFINISHED = 'YES' won't be confusing to anyone.

Comment: +1 using function-based indexes to pick out a few NULL values in the column will speed up queries as long as they use the same expression as used to generate the function-based index.

Comment: Good idea. If you have only the boolean field, you loose critical information. If you put the date_finished column, it is easy to understand and query, and makes a better representation of the real world: if it is null, it simply means it has not been completed. Having two fields is not normalized (having is_finished and date_finished): it is redundant, and redundancy leads to inconsistency (ie, you can have inconsistent values in a row) and lack of trust in the data, and failure prone queries and programs.

Comment: I see three conditions: (1) If it is finished, you know when it is finished, and you store that value. (2) If it is not finished, you do not have the finish datetime, you store null. (3) You don't know whether or not it is finished, you store uh, something. Seems to me the issue is along the lines of "what aspects of reality are you modeling in your database"? Must you be able to track all three conditions possible states, or will only the two discussed be found in the model? More to the point, how do your users know how to interpret your data? Do they guess or do they read your documentation?

Comment: I agree that clarity is important, however I doubt that this is unclear.  Using a null date to indicate that an event hasn't occurred is common practice and will be understood by nigh-on anyone. finish_date is null means it's not finished.  Besides, in a db, redundancy is the biggest sin.  Your db model should be as robust as possible, and redundancy leaves room for inconsistency.

Answer (score 5):

To all those who said the column is a waste of space:

Double Duty isn't a good thing in a database. Your primary goal should be clarity. Lots of systems, tools, people will use your data. If you disguise values by burying meaning inside of other columns you're BEGGING for another system or user to get it wrong.

And anyone who thinks it saves space is utterly wrong.

You'll need two indexes on that date column... one will be Function Based as OMG suggests. It will look like this:

NVL(Date_finished, TO_DATE('01-JAN-9999'))

So to find unfinished jobs you'll have to make sure to write the where clause correctly

It will look like this:

WHERE
NVL(Date_finished, TO_DATE('01-JAN-9999')) = TO_DATE('01-JAN-9999')

Yep. That's so clear. It's completely better than

WHERE
IS_Unfinished = 'YES'

The reason you'll want to have a second index on the same column is for EVERY OTHER query on that date... you won't want to use that index for finding jobs by date.

So let's see what you've accomplish with OMG's suggestion et al.

You've used more space, you've obfuscated the meaning of the data, you've made errors more likely... WINNER!

Sometime it seems programmers are still living in the 70's when a MB of hard drive space was a down payment on a house.

You can be space efficient about this without giving up a lot of clarity. Make the Is_unfinished either Y or NULL... *IF* you will only use that column to find 'work to do'. This will keep that index compact. It will only be as big as rows which are unfinished (in this way you exploit the unindexed nulls instead of being screwed by it). You put a little bit of space in your table, but over all it's less than the FBI. You need 1 byte for the column and you'll only index the unfinished rows so that' a small fraction of job and probably stays pretty constant. The FBI will need 7 bytes for EVERY ROW whether you're trying to find them or not. That index will keep pace with the size of the table, not just the size of the unfinished jobs.

### Reply to the comment by OMG

In his/her comment he/she states that to find unfinished jobs you'd just use

```
WHERE date_finished IS NULL
```

But in his answer he says

> You can create a function based index in order to get around the NULL values not being indexed

If you follow the link he points you toward, using NVL to replace null values with some other arbitrary value then I'm not sure what else there is to explain.

Comment: To find unfinished jobs, you'd just use `WHERE date_finished IS NULL`.  You fail to explain where the space is wasted--you just ramble about the need for two indexes.  And there's nothing that demonstrates that a NULLable date column is obfuscating data.

Comment: I would agree with you Stephanie to an extent, but in this case it's pretty obvious. I think (and this, of course, is an opinion) that most developers would intuit that "date_finished IS NULL" means that "there is no date when it was finished, so that means it has not been finished". Whether an additional Y/N column is needed would need to be thought about on a case-by-case basis, IMHO.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but you said 'most'. That means that there are some that won't. That means there's a potential for misinterpreting, misunderstanding etc. And why assume that only developers will ever touch the data. What if there's a report that needs run from there for business people? So now you're either going to hope that THEY also interpret the empty spot in the date_finished column as it's still running or you're going to calculate that column as NVL2(Date_finished, 'N', 'Y') Is_unfinished. why not just select it?

Comment: Besides, you still don't save any space. Even if you use a smarter FBI (See http://tinyurl.com/nullindexes) than the article OMG linked suggests using, the extra ,0) in the index takes up as much space as the column does. At least in my calculations on a 1MM row table.

Comment: @Stephanie - Why can't you create a view called vCompletedWorkFlow that filters out all null values and tell the business people to use that view for their reports?

Comment: @KP - Ohmmmmmmm Ohmmmmmmm Views are my friend. Ohmmmmmmm Ohmmmmmm

Comment: Gunny, well first of all, you're not trying to filter out the null, you're trying to filter out the not nulls. Once the job has a completed time, i.e. not null, it's considered finished. But why? And then you'll also need a view for uncompleted_work_flow, and then a view for all work flow. Right? or are you going to allow both access to the view AND the table directly? And THAT'S less confusing? and all this in an effort to avoid a column that makes your data clear? This isn't he 80's and this clearly wasn't a high performance app or he'd never use a table for that.

Comment: Unless there's a defined situation in which a workflow can be finished without its date being known then I'd rely on the date column, and maybe a virtual column (11g+) to indicate "finished or not". It's true that disk space is cheap, but data is now even cheaper, and we often deal with systems with far more than even 10 years ago.

By the way don't forget that the rowid in the index leaf block accounts for 12 bytes (as I recall) regardless of the length of the indexed data.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it a good or bad idea? I've heard like you can't have an index on a column with NULL values, so "where data_finished is not null" will be very slow on big tables.

Oracle does index *nullable fields*, but does not index *`NULL` values*

This means that you can create an index on a field marked `NULL`, but the records holding `NULL` in this field won't make it into the index.

This, on its turn, means that if you make `date_finished NULL`, the index will be **less in size**, as the `NULL` values won't be stored in the index.

So the queries involving equality of range searches on `date_finished` will in fact perform better.

The downside of this solution, of course, is that the queries involving the `NULL` values of `date_finished` will have to revert to full table scan.

You can work around this by creating two indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX ON mytable (date_finished)
CREATE INDEX ON mytable (DECODE(date_finished, NULL, 1))
```

and use this query to find unfinished work:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   DECODE(date_finished, NULL, 1) = 1
```

This will behave like partitioned index: the complete works will be indexed by the first index; the incomplete ones will be indexed by the second.

If you don't need to search for complete or incomplete works, you can always get rid of the appropriate indexes.

Comment: Indexing for search on date_finished = NULL is an optimization.  (Intuitively, this is likely to be needed as data is added.)  The is_finished column likewise is an optimization as it is derivable from date_finished.  The function based index, is likely to cause less problems.  Failure to use it in a query will degrade to in unindexed search, and there is no risk of conflicting information as with is_finished and date_finished.

Comment: I would add Boolean fields make for little used indexes. Unless the ration of True to False is something like 10 to 1 then the optimiser will ignore the index and (quite correctly) go for a table space scan or hopefully another index.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of table design, I think it's good that you removed the `is_finished` column as you said that it isn't necessary (it's redundant). There's no need to store extra data if it isn't necessary, it just wastes space. In terms of performance, I don't see this being a problem for NULL values. They should be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

I would use nulls as indexes work, as already mentioned in other answers, for all queries apart from "WHERE date_finished IS NULL" (so it depends if you need to use that query). I definitely wouldn't use outliers like year 9999 as suggested by the answer:

> you could also use a "dummy" value (such as 31 December 9999) as the date_finished value for unfinished workflows

Outliers like year 9999 affect performance, because (from http://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2007/12/13/outlier-values-an-enemy-of-the-index/):

> The selectivity of a range scan is basically calculated by the CBO to be the **number of values in the range of interest** divided by the **full range of possible values** (IE. the max value minus the min value)

If you use a value like 9999 then the DB will think the range of values being stored in the field is e.g. 2008-9999 rather than the actual 2008-2010; so any range query (e.g. "between 2008 and 2009") will appear to be covering a tiny % of the range of possible values, vs. actually covering about half the range. It uses this statistic to say, if the % of the ths possible values covered is high, probably a lot of rows will match, and then a full table scan will be faster than an index scan. It won't do this correctly if there are outliers in the data.

Comment: in this particular case I think it would be more important to be able to select workflows that are unfinished, than those that were finished within a specific data range. It might be possible to combine OMG's answer with Justin's comment on my answer - request the DBAs to set up a function-based index, and threaten them with having to maintain the histograms otherwise!

Answer (score 1):

good idea to remove the deriveable value column as others have said.

one more thought is that by removing the column, you will avoid paradoxical conditions that you will need to code around, such as what happens when the is_finished = No and the finished_date = yesterday... etc.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the indexed / non-indexed columns, wouldn't it be easier to simply JOIN two tables, like this:

```
-- PostgreSQL
CREATE TABLE workflow(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
  , name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE workflow_finished(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES workflow
  , date_finished date NOT NULL
);
```

Thus, if a record exists in workflow_finished, this workflow's completed, else it isn't. It seems to me this is rather simple.

When querying for unfinished workflows, the query becomes:

```
-- Only unfinished workflow items
SELECT workflow.id
FROM workflow
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM workflow_finished
  WHERE workflow_finished.id = workflow.id);
```

Maybe you want the original query? With a flag and the date? Query like this then:

```
-- All items, with the flag and date
SELECT
    workflow.id
  , CASE
    WHEN workflow_finished.id IS NULL THEN 'f'
    ELSE                                   't'
    END AS is_finished
  , workflow_finished.date_finished
FROM
            workflow
  LEFT JOIN workflow_finished USING(id);
```

For consumers of the data, views can and should be created for their needs.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to a function-based index, you could also use a "dummy" value (such as 31 December 9999, or alternatively one day before the earliest expected date_finished value) as the date_finished value for unfinished workflows.

EDIT: Alternative dummy date value, following comments.

Comment: Dummy values are rather dangerous because of the problems they cause for the optimizer.  With the most basic statistics, if Oracle knows that the min date_finished is, say, 2009-12-31, and the max date_finished is 9999-12-31, it's going to assume that a query for all the rows finished in 2010 would return 1/7990 th of the data in the table which is almost certainly grossly incorrect.  If you're careful to gather histograms constantly, you can mitigate the problem, but it will come back to bite you at the least opportune moment.

Comment: My gut reaction is "Ick!".  (On the other hand I don't feel it's a bad answer, just one I wouldn't use personally).  Using a default value to indicate that something doesn't contain a meaningful value is generally fraught with peril, especially when it comes to maintenance.  Experience tells me that if a column doesn't contain a meaningful value it should be left NULL.

Comment: As a rule of thumb I agree, Bob, but in this case there is the issue of performance when accessing unfinished workflows.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the single-column solution.

However, in the databases I use most often NULLs are included in indexes, so your common case of searching for open workflows will be fast whereas in your case it will be slower.  Because the case of searching for open workflows is likely to be one of the most common things you do, you may need the redundant column simply to support that search.

Test for performance to see if you can use the better solution performance-wise, then fall back to the less-good solution if necessary.